# How to search the keyword using ajax in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Not showing any data from php into ajax. Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
 Search Box:<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
 <div id="search1"></div>
```

**AJAX:**

```
        $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
                 $.ajax({  //GR ID Generation
                  method: "GET",
                  url: "search_rep.php?invo="+search,
                })

                  .done(function( msg ) {
        $("#search").html(msg); 
        $("#search1").val();      
        });
```

**PHP:**

```
    $in  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['invo']);
    $msg = '';
    if(strlen($in) > 0 && strlen($in) < 20){
      $row = mysql_query("SELECT Bot_Name
                        FROM bot_info 
                        WHERE Bot_Name 
                        LIKE '%$in%'and  Bot_Type='Printed'",$con );
      while($result = mysql_fetch_array($row)){
        $msg .= $result['Bot_Name'] . "<br />";
      }
    }
```

Output should be shown as google search engine once You type a word automatic all sentences are shown regarding to that word.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be echoing any data out onto the page in PHP. Consider trying

```
$in  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['invo']);
$msg = '';
if(strlen($in) > 0 && strlen($in) < 20){
  $row = mysql_query("SELECT Bot_Name
                    FROM bot_info 
                    WHERE Bot_Name 
                    LIKE '%$in%'and  Bot_Type='Printed'",$con );
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array($row)){
    $msg .= $result['Bot_Name'] . "<br />";
  }
}
echo $msg;
```

You may also want to look at using MySQLi rather than the soon depreciated MySQL in PHP.

If that fails to work, it may possibly be an issue with your database or another area of your code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {
     if (str.length == 0) {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
         return;
     } else {
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
             }
         }
         xmlhttp.open("GET", "cities.php?invo="+str, true);
         xmlhttp.send();
     }
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form>
First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
```

PHP/Ajax --> cities.php

```
$query=mysql_query("select name from cities", $con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$a[]=$row['name'];
}
$q = $_REQUEST["invo"];
$hint = "";
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Output is right..But how to show it , so that it look like a search engine..